# Prefixing all URLs in Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I would like to prefix all URLs in my Meteor app using Iron Router with a random constant string. I am thinking it might make it more secure. How do I do it?

Comment: the same random string for all urls, or a different random string for each?

Comment: Same. That's why it is constant :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use Meteor's random package: `meteor add random` and call `Random.id([n])`, where `n` is the length of the random string you want. See [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/random) for more details.

Comment: Nah, I can sort of generate a random constant myself. Here: 353424019874509274084